# Filter array that comes from backend in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, redux, react-redux, next.js

I have ask another questions. But I get all unuse answer. I actually not getting proper solutions.

Here I get an array from backend using redux.

`const { movies, message } = useAppSelector(state => state.movies);`

Here in `state.movies` has an object of two fields. One is `movies` and another is `message`. I defined type when I create redux reducers. Here in component I just getting this. `movies` type is `array` (Actually I am geting an array from backend by this movies field). `message` type is `string`.

In one word. here `movies` is array and `message` is string. I found this two field on `state.movies`.

Now I want to filter this `movies`-

```
const mathches = movies.filter((movie: movie ) => {
    const escapeRegExp = (str: string) => str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), "gi");
    return movie.name.match(regex);
})
```

But Here I am getting one error like-
`Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'never'`.

Here I can understand the problem. Problem is movies is array that cant understand typescripts. I have to define or tell that `movies` field is array. But how can I tell or define it.

Here is full component-

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

//Redux
import { wrapper } from "Redux/Store";
import { getMovies } from "Redux/Action/movieAction";
import { useAppSelector } from "Redux/Hook";

//Components
import Search from "Components/Movies/Search";
import Lists from "Components/Movies/Lists";

type movie = {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    releaseDate: string;
    watchedDate: string;
}

const Movies: NextPage = () => {
    const { movies, message } = useAppSelector(state => state.movies);
    const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState<[]>(movies);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
    useEffect(() => {
        let mathches = []
        if (search.length > 0) {
            mathches = movies.filter((movie: movie ) => {
                const escapeRegExp = (str: string) => str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
                const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), "gi");
                return movie.name.match(regex);
            })
        }
        setMovieList(mathches);
    }, [search, movies])
    return (
        <Container maxWidth={false} disableGutters>
            <Search setSearch={setSearch} />
            <Lists movies={movieList} />
        </Container>
    );
};
export default Movies;
```

Comment: See [TS docs for Arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays).

Comment: I see but can't understand anythings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here.

1. Your state definition has wrong generic type
2. useAppSelector is returning `never` type

The solution to the first problem would be to define `movieList` state with proper type like this:

```
const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState<movie[]>(movies);
```

As for the second problem, verify that you have defined your redux-toolkit types properly, see docs here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

If all else fails, you can cast your hook return type to a custom type like this:

```
type MovieReducer = {
  movies: movies[];
  message: string; // check if this is the correct type
}


const { movies, message } = useAppSelector((state) => state.movies) as unknown as MovieReducer;
```

Comment: What is the questions and what is the answer. Here question is about array filtering. But what answer you placed.

Comment: I see no problem with the filter operation here, The issue the op is facing is related to typescript, not array filtering.